# Problems with space and line break when merging Javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I have spent some time to look for an answer and have implemented many of the solution but they don't work. Basically, I have 2 dictionary objects in javascript and they are as followed when I console.log:

```
obj1 = {"\n  key1\n  ": "\n   aaaaaaaa\n  ", "\n  key2\n":["\n  f\n  ","\n   e\n"], "\n   key3\n    ":["\n  fda\n", "\n    das\n"]}

obj2 = {"key2":["h","k","z"], "key3": "zzz"}
```

I want to merge the 2 objects into this:

```
obj3 = {"key1":["a"], "key2":["f","e","h", "k","z"], "key3":["fda", "das","zzz","bbb"]}
```

I have tried to use:

```
obj3= Object.assign({},obj1, obj2);
```

but the result is:

```
obj3 = {"\n  key1\n  ":["\n   a\n   ","\n    b\n "], "\n  key2\n":["\n  f\n  ","\n   e\n"], "\n   key3\n    ":["\n  fda\n", "\n    das\n"], "key2":["h","k","z"], "key3":["zzz","bbb"]}
```

Clearly the keys don't match because of those line breaks. I tried another way below but it throws an error "object.map() is not a function". I debugged and found out the problem was because "key1" has only one value "a". If I add another value to its list of values, the code works perfectly. However, I need it to work when a key has only one value also. I've stuck on this for way too long. Please help!

```
const result = Object.keys(obj1)
  .reduce((acc, key) => ({...acc,
    [key.trim()]: obj1[key]
      .map(val => val.trim())
      .concat(obj2[key.trim()] || [])
  }), {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: why are there line breaks? seems very odd.

Comment: They are even forbidden, same as tabs, etc. so probably invalid JSON. In case it would be string there would be almost no problem (keys better should have quotes and values must have), but obj1 looks, like partially parsed string??

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, Takes entries from one object which is defected and replace space characters by space, and then merge keys and values accordingly

```js
let obj1 = {"\n  key1\n  ":["\n   a\n  "], "\n  key2\n":["\n  f\n  ","\n   e\n"], "\n   key3\n    ":["\n  fda\n", "\n    das\n"]}
let obj2 = {"key2":["h","k","z"], "key3":["zzz"]}


let merger = (obj1,obj2)=>{
  Object.entries(obj1).forEach(([key,value])=>{
    let newKey = key.replace(/\s+/g,'')
    if(obj2[newKey]){
      value.forEach(v=>{
        obj2[newKey].push(v.replace(/\s+/g,''))
      })
    } else {
      obj2[newKey] = value.map(v=> v.replace(/\s+/g,''))
    }
  })
  return obj2
}
console.log(merger(obj1,obj2))
```

Comment: I still run into the error: value.map is not a function. Same for the other answer. Isn't there a way to turn the single value of "key1" into an array?

Comment: @Alice_inwonderland in provide example all the values are array only, so if you have any non array value, you need to check before using `map` and manipulate accordingly

Comment: My apology, just fixed my post. Obj1 has key 1 as : "\n  key1\n  ": "\n   aaaaaaa\n  "

Could you show me a way to treat objects that are not arrays like this? I've dug for a long time without a solution

Answer (score 0):

Trim the keys and use map() to clean the data in the arrays

```js
obj1 = {"\n  key1\n  ":["\n   a\n  "], "\n  key2\n":["\n  f\n  ","\n   e\n"], "\n   key3\n    ":["\n  fda\n", "\n    das\n"]}

obj2 = {"key2":["h","k","z"], "key3":["zzz"]}

const clean = str => str.trim()
var cleanedObject = Object.entries(obj1).reduce((o, [key, values]) => {
  const cKey = key.trim()
  o[cKey] = values.map(clean).concat(o[cKey] || [])
  return o
}, obj2)

console.log(cleanedObject)
```

Comment: I still run into the error: value.map is not a function. Same for the other answer. Isn't there a way to turn the single value of "key1" into an array?

Comment: um, so what is different from what I have since I do not get the error? If code is different, then make an example like that.

Comment: My apology, just fixed my post. Obj1 has key 1 as : "\n  key1\n  ": "\n   aaaaaaa\n  "

Could you show me a way to treat objects that are not arrays like this? I've dug for a long time without a solution